# How to Add a Class to first post in Wordpress Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I"m running multiple loops on a page and on one of the loops I need to add a class to the first post that way I can offset the margin. How can I add a class to the first post from the wp_query?

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=news&posts_per_page=3');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID ?>
    <div class="post-container">
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I need to add the class to the main div container which has the class "post-container".

Thank you the fix below works perfect but what do I do if I want to use it for a normal loop instead of a wp_query? like this

```
<?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 3, 'post__not_in'=>$do_not_duplicate));
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
$first = false;
if( $my_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) { $first = true; }
```

And then your line with  you do this:

```
<div class="post-container <?= ($first ? 'classname' : ''); ?>">
```

Not tested for syntax errors.

So try this:

```
<?php 
$first = true;
query_posts(array('showposts' => 3, 'post__not_in'=>$do_not_duplicate));
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();

        echo '<div class="post-container '.($first ? 'classname' : '').'"></div>';

        if ($first) {
            $first = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but where do I define the class, and do I place this within the "post-container" div?

Comment: Thank you that works perfect when I"m using it for $my_query but what do I do if I want to use it with a normal wordpress loop? I've added the code also above

Comment: Added another example

Comment: Thank you, this post has helped a lot, although is there a way where I can add a class to the last post instead of the first?

Comment: I never did that, but the logic is the same. You need to count how many posts have been found and then do counter, when counter equals to the number of total posts found, add the class.